# Deadlock involving SELECT FOR UPDATE

Tags: sql, postgresql, concurrency, deadlock, select-for-update

I have transaction with several queries. First, a select rows with `FOR UPDATE` lock:

```sql
SELECT f.source_id FROM files AS f WHERE
    f.component_id = $1 AND
    f.archived_at IS NULL
FOR UPDATE
```

Next, there is an update query:

```sql
UPDATE files AS f SET archived_at = NOW()
WHERE
hw_component_id = $1 AND
f.source_id = ANY($2::text[])
```

And then there is an insert:

```sql
INSERT INTO files AS f (
    source_id,
    ...
)
VALUES (..)
ON CONFLICT (component_id, source_id) DO UPDATE
SET archived_at = null,
is_valid = excluded.is_valid
```

I have two application instances and sometimes I see deadlock errors in PostgreSQL log:

```
ERROR:  deadlock detected
DETAIL:  Process 3992939 waits for ShareLock on transaction 230221362; blocked by process 4108096.
Process 4108096 waits for ShareLock on transaction 230221365; blocked by process 3992939.
Process 3992939: SELECT f.source_id FROM files AS f WHERE f.component_id = $1 AND f.archived_at IS NULL FOR UPDATE
Process 4108096: INSERT INTO files AS f (source_id, ...) VALUES (..) ON CONFLICT (component_id, source_id) DO UPDATE SET archived_at = null, is_valid = excluded.is_valid
CONTEXT:  while locking tuple (41116,185) in relation \"files\"
```

I assume that it may be caused by `ON CONFLICT DO UPDATE` statement, which may update rows which are not locked by previous `SELECT FOR UPDATE`

But I can't understand how can `SELECT ... FOR UPDATE` query cause deadlock if it is the first query in transaction. There is not queries before it.
Can `SELECT ... FOR UPDATE` statement lock several rows and then wait for other rows in condition to be unlocked?

Comment: `select...for update` does exactly that.  If you do not want it to wait for locked rows, then add `skip locked` at the end.  Please see the docs:  https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/sql-select.html#SQL-FOR-UPDATE-SHARE

Comment: @MikeOrganek: `SKIP LOCKED` seems like the wrong tool. You may be thinking of `NOWAIT`?

Comment: @ErwinBrandstetter Either one or even a timeout might be appropriate.  It is hard to tell what OP is trying to accomplish with the disjointed snippets of code.

Comment: `SKIP LOCKED` only makes sense with queuing-type queries, where you go on using the actually locked rows. Does not seem to apply.

Comment: @ErwinBrandstetter  Some other process is locking the rows before `select. . . for update` is run.  That sounds to me like whatever OP is doing should be refactored into a queuing operation, but again, I do not see enough information here to say that is the case.  Tell me my comments are wrong, and I will remove them.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

`SELECT FOR UPDATE` is no safeguard against deadlocks. It just locks rows. Locks are acquired along the way, in the order instructed by `ORDER BY`, or in arbitrary order in the absence of `ORDER BY`. The best defense against deadlocks is to lock rows in consistent order across the whole transaction - and doing likewise in all concurrent transactions. Or, as [the manual puts it](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/explicit-locking.html#LOCKING-DEADLOCKS):

> The best defense against deadlocks is generally to avoid them by being
> certain that all applications using a database acquire locks on
> multiple objects in a consistent order.

Else, this can happen (*row1*, *row2*, ... are rows numbered according to the virtual consistent order):

```
T1: SELECT FOR UPDATE ...          -- lock row2, row3
        T2: SELECT FOR UPDATE ...  -- lock row4, wait for T1 to release row2 
T1: INSERT ... ON CONFLICT ...     -- wait for T2 to release lock on row4

--> deadlock
```

Adding **`ORDER BY`** to your `SELECT... FOR UPDATE` *may* already avoid your deadlocks. (It would avoid the one demonstrated above.) Or this happens and you have to do more:

```
T1: SELECT FOR UPDATE ...          -- lock row2, row3
        T2: SELECT FOR UPDATE ...  -- lock row1, wait for T1 to release row2 
T1: INSERT ... ON CONFLICT ...     -- wait for T2 to release lock on row1

--> deadlock
```

Everything within the transaction must happen in consistent order to be absolutly sure.

Also, your `UPDATE` does not seem to be in line with the `SELECT FOR UPDATE`. `component_id` <> `hw_component_id`. Typo?
Also, `f.archived_at IS NULL` does not guarantee that the later `SET archived_at = NOW()` only affects these rows. You would have to add `WHERE f.archived_at IS NULL` to the `UPDATE` be in line. (Seems like a good idea in any case?)

> I assume that it may be caused by `ON CONFLICT DO UPDATE` statement,
> which may update rows which are not locked by previous `SELECT FOR UPDATE`.

As long as the UPSERT (`ON CONFLICT DO UPDATE`) sticks to the consistent order, that wouldn't be a problem. But that may be hard or impossible to enforce.

> Can `SELECT ... FOR UPDATE` statement lock several rows and then wait for other rows in condition to be unlocked?

Yes, as explained above, locks are acquired along the way. It can have to stop and wait half way through.

#### `NOWAIT`

If all that still can't resolve your deadlocks, the slow and sure method is to use [Serializable Isolation Level](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/transaction-iso.html#XACT-SERIALIZABLE). Then you have to be prepared for serialization failures and retry the transaction in this case. Considerably more expensive overall.

Or it might be enough to add `NOWAIT`:

```sql
SELECT FROM files
WHERE  component_id = $1
AND    archived_at IS NULL
ORDER  BY id   -- whatever you use for consistent, deterministic order
FOR    UPDATE NOWAIT;
```

[The manual:](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/sql-select.html#SQL-FOR-UPDATE-SHARE)

> With `NOWAIT`, the statement reports an error, rather than waiting, if a selected row cannot be locked immediately.

You may even skip the `ORDER BY` clause with `NOWAIT` if you cannot establish consistent order with the UPSERT anyway.

Then you have to catch that error and retry the transaction. Similar to catching serialization failures, but much cheaper - and less reliable. For example, multiple transactions can still interlock with their UPSERT alone. But it gets less and less likely.

Comment: Thanks for detailed explanation, it helps a lot. But for me still not clear the case when "locks are acquired along the way". I tried reproduce it in console, I made
BEGIN; SELECT FOR UPDATE where component_id=1 in one console, then I insert new record with component_id=1 in separate transaction. Then I started new transaction and executed BEGIN; SELECT FOR UPDATE where component_id=1. Console expectedly frozen. Then I run update query in my first transaction, and it was successfully executed, without deadlock error. How can I reproduce the case when deadlock occurred?

Comment: I forgot about ordering. I added ORDER BY to FOR UPDATE statement and now problem is reproducing. Thanks!

Comment: Why f.archived_at IS NULL does not guarantee that the later SET archived_at = NOW() only affects these rows?  If for update lock rows initially, and then rows being updated should be never changed from the previous select. Am I wrong？ Looking forward to your reply.

Comment: @YangXu: Rows with `archived_at IS NULL` get locked with `FOR UPDATE` and can't be changed by other transactions until released. But the later `UPDATE` might update *additional* rows if it does not also *also* restrict to `archived_at IS NULL`. Plus, there may be additional rows with `archived_at IS NULL` that were created in the meantime.

Comment: @ErwinBrandstetter Does this f.source_id = ANY($2::text[]) is filled with the id list from select for update? I am ask based on this precondition If there filter id from the previous, and then  archived_at IS NULL is not needed in update SQL. Am I right?

Comment: @ErwinBrandstetter Thank you for your quick reply, I am still getting another question about your detailed article, What's the ORDER BY effect? Since below your 'Adding ORDER BY to your SELECT... FOR UPDATE may already avoid your deadlocks.' there is just another deadlock example. I didn't get the real effect here.

Comment: @romsuhov I don't understand why reproducing the problem after you added ORDER BY, shouldn't ORDER BY shorten the deadlock situation? So what's the relationship here between ORDER BY and your operation?